# Date using BETWEEN in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, between

I want to display the records using two different date. I tried using the Between

```
select * from billing where select_client = '2' and order_date BETWEEN '01/06/2018' and '30/06/2018' order by id ASC
```

It returns JULY month records also. I tried used >= and <=. That query also returns same record.

```
select * from billing where select_client = '2' and order_date >= '01/06/2018' and order_date <= '30/06/2018' order by id ASC
```

Kindly help me out to get only the records between the two dates. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Show sample data please. What is the data type of column `order_date`?

Comment: order_date data type is in varchar. The value of order_date is stored in this "07/06/2018" format. If I change the data type to date. All the records in the field will change to "0000:00:00". Kindly advice me to fix this because client already have stored the bill in the varchar datatype order_date format

Comment: Do not store Dates as a varchar. Store it as a date type. To compare it as Dates, you have to convert it to dates

Comment: If I change the data type to date. All the records in the field will change to "0000:00:00". Kindly advice me to fix this because client already have stored the bill in the varchar datatype order_date format

Comment: From the answer provided below, you should be able to figure out how to fix the dates, and then the data type, which will lead to an infinitely better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the strings to a date to compare it:

```
select * from billing where select_client = '2' and STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/06/2018','%d/%m/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('30/06/2018','%d/%m/%Y') order by id ASC
```

Comment: I tried this query. I returns "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0188 sec)"

Comment: Can you Show examples

Comment: "This query " select * from billing where select_client = '2' and STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/06/2018','%d/%m/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('30/06/2018','%d/%m/%Y') order by id ASC" returns empty set

Answer (score 0):

wrong date format. if `order_date` is mysql `DATE` then format should be `2018-06-01`